# jQuery Tab: Able to change the tab but content does not load

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I am trying to change tabs based on the button click but somehow its not working. It does change the tab but does not load the content and does not call select or show events either. This is how my markup looks like:

```
<div id="content">
   <ul>
      <li><a id="tab1" href="Page1.aspx"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="tab3" href="Page2.aspx"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="tab4" href="Page3.aspx"><span>Tab 3</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="tab5" href="Page4.aspx"><span>Tab 4</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="tab7" href="Page5.aspx"><span>Tab 5</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>


<button id="Button1" onclick="JavaScript:return ChangeTab();">Go to next tab</button>

function ChangeTab()
    {
         var $tabs = $('#content').tabs();
         var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
         $tabs.tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
         //$tabs.tabs('select', selected + 1);
         return false;
    }
```

This is how i am initializing the tabs:

```
$( "#content" ).tabs();
```

Can someone please point out what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using to select the tab seems to be incorrect. Some of the calls you are making are passing too many (or incorrect) parameters. You should do something like this:

```
$('#Button1').click(function()
{
    var currentTab = $('#content').tabs('option', 'selected');
    var newTab = parseInt(currentTab) + 1;

    $('#content').tabs('select', newTab);
});
```

Comment: I tried like this earlier but it gives me the content div in the currentTab variable. I know its supposed to give me the selected index. Any idea why is it doing that? The code i have in the question does give me the selected index number.

Comment: The documentation states it should be the index. However, it looks like every time you were calling `ChangeTab`, you were re-initializing the tabs control. That may be interfering with things.

Comment: If i copy your code, it give me DIV in the currentTab. If i re-initialize the tabs in the click function, it gives me the correct index and activates the next tab. But still it does not load the content.

Comment: i guess it has something to do with the href attribute. i have to manually redirect the page to the href URL.

Comment: this should have worked if i had my tab initialization outside the function. i was looking $tab variable and thats why i had to re-initialize it every time. Thanks for the help. its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ChangeTab(){
         var $tabs = $('#content');
         var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
         $tabs.tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
         $tabs.tabs('select', selected + 1);
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZffYf/

Comment: selected gives me DIV and not the index of the selected tab. Thats the problem i facing with the code on jQuery website's tab example as well. Let me update the example code to show how i am initializing the tabs. May be i am doing something wrong there.

Comment: i was initializing the tabs inside a function so i was loosing the tab variable. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong within your HTML or Javascript code. It should work: here is a minimal working demo http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/Csdf4/

HTML code

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">E</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">Content A</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">Content B</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">Content C</div>
    <div id="tabs-4">Content D</div>
    <div id="tabs-5">Content E</div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Go next" onclick="goNext();" />
```

Javascript code

```
var $tabs = $( "#tabs" );

// initialize once
$tabs.tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        console.log( "select event" );
    },
    show: function(event, ui) {
        console.log( "show event" );
    }
});


function goNext() {
    // only "select" the next element in the handler
    var index = $tabs.tabs( "option", "selected" );
    $tabs.tabs( "select", index+1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#content').tabs();

    $("#content").tabs("option", "selected", 1);


    var index = $("#content").tabs("option", "selected");

    $("#button1").click(function() {
        $("#content").tabs("option", "selected", 1);
    });


    window.setInterval(yourfunction, 1000);

    function yourfunction() {
        var x = (index++) % 3;
        $("#content").tabs("option", "selected", x);
    }
});
```

Try This example in Fiddler, sorry i don't explain in detail.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3kYS/)